# How does the distance between the electrodes of a Galvanic cell affect the voltage between the electrodes?

Tags: electrochemistry

I am trying to figure out how the distance between the electrodes of a galvanic cell affects the voltage between said electrons if everything else is kept the same. I have spent a few hours looking on the internet but I could not find anything.

Citations would be very much appreciated

Comment: Open or closed circuit voltage?

Comment: Hint: In an electrolyte solution, what factors affect resistance, *R*? Another keyword is internal cell resistance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance

Comment: Also remember, as Poutnik pointed out, when we talk about the voltage of Galvanic cells, we are not drawing any current. In older books, it was called null-point potentiometry.

Comment: The circuit is an open circuit. The set up lookes something like this one on the left
https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0013468618313689-fx1.jpg

Comment: According to this website the resistance of an electrolyte solution is $R=\rho\frac{l}{a}$
https://www.gamry.com/Framework%20Help/HTML5%20-%20Tripane%20-%20Audience%20A/Content/EIS/Theory/Physical%20Electrochemistry%20and%20Circuit%20Elements/Electrolyte%20Resistance.htm

And isn't the resistance only half the story? Since the voltage will remain the same if the resistance changes but the current changes inversely

I do not understand what you mean in the second comment by "we are not drawing any current"

Answer (score 3):

Apparently User$128138$ has not really understood the reasons and the differences for using inner and outer resistances.

Let's start from the very beginning. A galvanic cell has a certain theoretical voltage $E$ which is described by Nernst law. If the cell is connected to an outer resistance $R$, it produces a current $I$, which is **not** directly given by the elementary formula $I = E/R$. No ! One must take into account the inner resistance $r =\pu{\rho \frac{l}{a}}$. So that the current $I$ is linked to $E$ by the following formula $(1)$ $${I = \frac{E}{R + r}...,,,,....({1})}$$ In this case, the measured voltage on the electrodes is $E'$ < $E$ :

${E' = E - rI = E ( 1 - \frac{r}{R+r})}$, and $I ≠ 0$ , so that $E' < E$

If $R$ is infinite, the situation is like the sentence that User$128138$ does not understand, namely "we are not drawing any current". Here $I = 0$ and   $E' = E$.

If $R$ is finite, the cell produces a current $I$, which is related to the nominal voltage $E$ by the formula ($1$)

Hopefully the OP understands my explanation.